# Data Structure in C top and pop

Tags: c, data-structures

How do I fill out my **if-else** statement where if the letter are this then pop it, if not top the letters. I used `struct` to approach the problem.

```
typedef struct StackStruct{
 int*    darr;  
 int     size;  
 int     inUse; 
} Stack;

void push (Stack* s, int val){
  if (s->inUse >= s->size){
    s->size = s->size + 2;

    int *temp = ((int*)malloc (sizeof(int)* s->size));
    for(int i = 0; i < s->size; i++){
      temp[i] = s->darr[i];
    }
    free(s->darr);
    s->darr=temp;

   }

  s->darr[s->inUse] = val;
  s->inUse = s->inUse + 1;
}

int isEmpty (Stack* s){
  if ( s->inUse == 0)
    return TRUE;
  else
    return FALSE;
}


int top (Stack* s){
  return (  s->darr[s->inUse-1] );
}

void init (Stack* s){
 s->size = 2;
 s->darr = (int*) malloc ( sizeof (int) * s->size );
 s->inUse  = 0;
}


Stack pop (Stack s){
  s.inUse -= 1;
  return s;
}
```

in my **if-else** statement the stuff I commented out wasn't working within my code

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
   Stack st1;

    init (&st1);


    char input[300];
  
    if('a' || 'b' || 'c' || 'd'){
    //push to stack
    //push(st1, 20);
  }

if( 'm' || 'n' || 'o' || 'p'){
  //check the top of the stack 
   int a;
   a = top(&st1);
   printf("this is top %d", a);

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an input statement like

```
printf( "Give me a letter: " );
scanf( "%s", input );
```

and you're using `input[0]` as your input letter, then you could use the `strchr` libary function declared in `string.h` and do something like this:

```
if ( strchr( "abcd", input[0] ) )
{
  push( st1, input[0] );
}
else if ( strchr( "mnop", input[0] ) )
{
  // get top
}
else
{
  // input not in abcd or mnop, do something else
}
```

`strchr` searches the string argument for the specified character; if the character is found, it returns the address of the character in the string, otherwise it returns `NULL`.

Comment: what if im trying to get one of those letters not all the letters?